# Como subo mas de 20 archivos a mi servidor con php?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost

Estoy trabajando con **php** y **mysql**, y utilizo el localhost de `wampserver`,estoy haciendo un sistema que me permita subir mas de un solo archivo al mismo tiempo, y ya logré que me suba mas de uno, pero solo son 20 los que sube, tengo el problema que no me deja subir mas de 20 archivos al mismo tiempo, y ya modifique las variables `upload_max_filesize = 64M` `max_file_uploads = 400` `post_max_size = 64M` `max_execution_time = 30` también incluí la clase `upload.php`, y no se si en esta deba configurar algo mas?

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/5215609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crear un archivo .htaccess dentro de tu proyecto y dentro de el guarda la siguiente configuración:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M 
php_value max_execution_time 500 
php_value max_input_time 500
```

ya dependiendo de cuantos megas pesen en total tus archivos tendrás que modificar los valores.

Comment: y este donde lo debo mandar llamar o guardar?

Comment: Solo debes de guardar el archivo en la carpeta de tu proyecto junto a los demás archivos .php, ten en cuenta que estas modificaciones solo afectaran al proyecto donde este guardado el archivo

Comment: va! muchas gracias

Comment: eres un genio amigo, muchas gracias